# What is the meaning of lined?

Tags: meaning

> She wore a crimson robe lined with white fur.

What does lined mean? Does it mean for example that the cuffs are made of fur and the rest is made of red cotton? Could you provide an image that describes something like this? Lined means form a line, but what kind of line? Is the sentence above just very generic and not specific enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that someone put a [lining](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lining) in it.

> a material or substance that covers the inside surface of something:

The verb is [line](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/line)

> to cover the inside surface of something:

Therefore what you have is a crimson robe with all the inside covered with fur.